# Automated change logs not generating with semantic-release on a non-master branch

Tags: node.js, git, npm, versioning, semantic-release

In my node project - I'm trying to implement [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) to generate release notes in the form of the changelogs, bump the project version number.

The same is installed in the project following the below command:

```
npm i -D semantic-release@next @semantic-release/git@next @semantic-release/commit-analyzer@next @semantic-release/release-notes-generator@next @semantic-release/npm@next @semantic-release/changelog@next
```

Here is the configuration in the `package.json` file:

```
"release": {
    "branches": [
      "qa"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
      "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      "@semantic-release/git"
    ]
  }
```

However, when I try to run `npx semantic-release --no-ci` to execute it throws this:

> **This test run was triggered on the branch qa, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from master, therefore a new version won’t be published.**

The entire stack trace is:

```
ℹ  Running semantic-release version 15.14.0
✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/changelog"
✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/git"
✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/changelog"
✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/git"
ℹ  This test run was triggered on the branch qa, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from master, therefore a new version won’t be published.
```

The [conventional commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) are done on the QA branch - I need to generate the changelog on the QA branch.

What is the right approach?

Comment: Does the same message also appear when utilizing the CLI argument, i.e. `--branch qa`

Comment: The `branches` option is only available in version 16.0.0. You are using version 15.14.0. You should upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @RobC the changelog is generated when I use `--branch=qa` as the parameter.

Comment: @PierreVanduynslager I shall check with `16.0.0` now and update

Comment: @ZameerAnsari, any news? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100 percent sure but the enhanced branch definition is:

```
branches: [
  {name: 'qa', prerelease: false}
]
```

As the changelog is generated when using the `--branch` flag it is possible that the branches definition in your config file is wrong.

You could try to configure the branch using the enhanced statement I suggested.